# Which methods of Google OAuth2 API accept login_hint as a parameter

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin, credential-manager

I am using the [Google Sign-In JavaScript client](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsignin) and also referencing the [Example App](https://credential-management-sample.appspot.com/)

The example app (app.js) tells me that login_hint is a valid option for the signIn method:

```
    // If the user is not signed in with expected account, let sign in.
return auth2.signIn({
  // Set `login_hint` to specify an intended user account,
  // otherwise user selection dialog will popup.
  login_hint: id || ''
});
```

But the reference manual does not say it does anything there but is only effective with the authorize() method. Elsewhere on the Web I see examples of it being also used with the init() method.

Can someone please clarify any/all places where the login_hint option is functionally active?

Comment: The `login_hint` option for `auth2.signIn()` is a new addition after the doc was published. Let me work with the documentation team update it.

Comment: Thank-you! Is it available with init() as well? @agektmr

Comment: I doubt it. Can you try yourself? Sorry I don't have an immediate environment to try it.

Comment: No worries. Not needed for me. Just saw someone else on the Web trying it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [login_hint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

> Optional. If your application knows which user is trying to
>   authenticate, it can use this parameter to provide a hint to the
>   Google Authentication Server. The server uses the hint to simplify the
>   login flow either by prefilling the email field in the sign-in form or
>   by selecting the appropriate multi-login session.
>
> Set the parameter value to an email address or sub identifier, which
>   is equivalent to the user's Google ID.
>
> To set this value in PHP, call the setLoginHint function:
>
> $client->setLoginHint('user@example.com');

Code for you:

```
options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder();
options.setAppPackageName('com.example.app');
options.setFetchBasicProfile(True);
//options.setPrompt('select_account');
options.setLoginHint('user@example.com');
options.setScope('profile').setScope('email');

auth2.signIn(options);
```