# Flutter ,Google apis wants choose gmail adress every time

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I'm using google calender API and google sign-in in Flutter but when I try to log in, google wants to choose Gmail address every time.

When I was using google sign in without google calender API, my app was logging in automatically after the first login. Then I added google calender API and Google starts to wants me to choose a Gmail account every time.

How can I choose Google signed-in account for google API?

There is the code.

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    clientId:"THIS IS CLIENT ID"
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    ],
  );


clientViaUserConsent(ClientId(googleSignIn.clientId, ''),
            [CalendarApi.CalendarScope], prompt)
        .then((AuthClient client) {
      Constants.baseCl = client;
    });



 void prompt(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: look for something called login hint  you can supply the email address it will attempt to login with if the user has more then one google account set up on their machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which methods of Google OAuth2 API accept login\_hint as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490476/which-methods-of-google-oauth2-api-accept-login-hint-as-a-parameter)

Comment: How can i implement this to flutter?My problem is not about google sign in actually.My problem is about choosing account for google api.

Comment: Hey buddy...Found any solution for this???